# The PHP is ran twice

Tags: php

I was trying to run a code that inserts new data in my DB but I've noticed that data was inputted twice each time I was running the code.
I've completely changed the code, It's just a Variable Session that increments each time I reloading the PHP page.

But each time I reload the page the incrementation goes by 2 instead of one 1.

Here is the code (It's really simple):

```
session_start();

echo "test";
echo strval($_SESSION["testCount"]);

if(isset($_SESSION["testCount"])){
    $_SESSION["testCount"] = $_SESSION["testCount"] + 1;
}
else{
    echo "TESSESSION";
    $_SESSION["testCount"] = 0;
}
```

NOTE: When I run it into privacy mod is working perfectly.

Comment: I'm using your link, and it seems to be incrementing by 1 -- did you change something?

Comment: check your access log (user agent, time, etc) to confirm that you make two requests per time

Comment: Well, I've changed nothing but I won't be surprised that comes only from my side. I've even tried to delete all my caches. But if it's only happening to me it's not a problem, I just won't it happen to everyone and have a lot of double info in my DB.

Comment: Have you tried disabling all your browser's addons/extensions/plugins? Tried with different browsers?

Comment: *inserts new data in my DB but I've noticed that data was inputted twice* ... May have nothing to do with your *session* vars. Show your db code. There could be a common fix to a well known programmer error.

Comment: Ok, So I tested it on other browser and also on privacy mod in chrome (which is the browser I was using), and it worked perfectly, so for sure, it might come from my chrome. I don't know why but it's not important till the bug is only on me. Because I can control the double entry in DB when it come from me. Everything should be fine know, thanks guys for your answers and your help.

Comment: Do you do what I suggested?

Comment: Look at your browsers debugger console. See if it is submitting more than one request. It's possible it is doing something like and OPTIONS request that is getting picked up in your code and then a second GET request, thus two calls for one real one.